# m1 pro macbookでsourcetreeからクローンしたらエラーが出る

Tags: macos, git, github, sourcetree

新型macbook pro 14インチを先日購入し、sourcetreeをダウンロードしてgithubと連携もし、クローンしてみたのですが、画像のようなエラーが出て調べても解決できませんでした
どなたかわかる人いましたらご教授お願いします。

環境ややったことは以下の通りです。

・sourcetree自体はwindowsで使っていた
・githubにリポジトリも作成済み
・windowsではクローンできる
・githubにmacの公開鍵は追加済み

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

スクリーンショットをよく見てみると[git](/questions/tagged/git)ではなく[mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial)としてcloneをしようとしているように見えます。

本来自動的に選択されたりするような気もしますが、どこかで選択を間違えていないか確認してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

SourceTreeで公開鍵を作成してもだめですか？

- SourceTreeで公開鍵作成
- GitHubに公開鍵を追加